# Android, Get a DecorView child

Tags: java, oop

I wonder if it is possible to get a decorViews child. For example if I have a decorView object and I know that the child of the decorView is a FrameLayout, is there someway for me to get the FrameLayout object just by using its parent?

Obviously I could use getViewById() in the traditional way, but if I only want to use the parent object, is it possible to get the FrameLayout object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about object inheritance?

If that is the case, then it is simple: Cast it.

Assuming you have a class "Foo" which is an ancestor-class of "Bar" (in other words: Bar is a "child" of Foo), then take this example:

```
Foo myFoo = getSomeFoo();
Bar myBar = (Bar)myFoo;
```

So, adapting this to your question:

```
View myView = getDecorView();
FrameLayout myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) myView;
```

or:

```
FrameLayout myFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) getDecorView();
```

You should protect the block making this call though as this will throw a `ClassCastException` if the instance returned by `getDecorView` is *not* a `FrameLayout` (or a (in)direct subclass of it). Simply add a try/catch block, or add a `throwing` declaration to the method containing this line. Whatever suits you best.